# Commerce Migrate module not listed in migrations

Tags: commerce, migrations

I installed the Commerce Migrate module, and its submodules, `commerce_migrate_commerce` and `csv_example`. When I run `drush migrate:status`, I see the migrations for the `csv_example` listed but none of the `commerce_migrate_commerce` ones?

I likely will have to write my own migration anyways, but I was confuse at this discrepancy.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. In MigrateToolsCommands.php, we have the following code:
[image]

If you dig into the error for the migrations in question, I see the error of `No database connection configured for source plugin variable`. When an item fails the `checkRequirements()`, it simply is not displayed in the list.

In SqlBase.php

[image]

it sets the default migration database as `migrate`. Being that the migrations themselves do not specify a key (since that is really site specific), it would rely on the default one, which I did not have set up in my settings.php.

EDIT:
I also found out one more issue: even AFTER I had set up a migrate database source key, it still wasn't working. I found that this modules is ONLY meant to migrate from D7. You can see this from the fact that that during the requirements check, it looks for existance of the `system` table, which only exists in d7.